# Include data in resultset not fulfilling the filter condition without using temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Please use following sample data.

```
declare @tbl table (id int, fid int, arrival datetime, created datetime)
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, DATEADD(dd, -10, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, DATEADD(dd, -10, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, DATEADD(dd, -10, GETDATE()), null
insert into @tbl select 2, 20, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -2, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 2, 20, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()), null
```

I would like to have all rows `between arrival '2011-02-25' and '2011-02-28'` which created after this date `'2011-02-20'` including created date null.

**Query1:**

```
select * from @tbl 
where arrival >= '2011-02-25' and arrival < '2011-02-28'
and created >= '2011-02-20'
```

Above query fetch two rows but I need 3rd row of FID = 10 which has created date null

Qery2: select row of FID = 20 which I don't need because it is not in range of Arrival date.

```
select * from @tbl 
where arrival >= '2011-02-25' and arrival < '2011-02-28'
and created >= '2011-02-20' OR created is null
```

This is sample data. The original query fetch data from different table and has joins with 10+ tables so I don't want to run query again to include rows in temp table.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, wanted to ask this but put wrong question. Thanks for your help.

```
declare @tbl table (id int, fid int, arrival datetime, created datetime)
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, DATEADD(dd, -10, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, DATEADD(dd, -10, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 1, 10, null, DATEADD(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 2, 20, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()), DATEADD(dd, -2, getdate())
insert into @tbl select 2, 20, null, DATEADD(dd, -2, getdate())

select * from @tbl
where arrival >= '2011-02-26' and arrival < '2011-02-28'
```

Need the third row of fid = 10 too where `arrival` date is `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want.

```
;with cte as
(
  select distinct fid
  from @tbl
  where
    arrival >= '2011-02-26' and
    arrival < '2011-02-28'
)
select *
from cte as C
  inner join @tbl as T
    on C.fid = T.fid
where
  (arrival >= '2011-02-26' and
   arrival < '2011-02-28') or
  arrival is null
```

Comment: ... and isnull(created, '2011-02-20') >= '2011-02-20'

Comment: Thanks @Mikael, yes that is the result what I want. I wanted to avoid re-running the whole query twice but I think this is the only solution. Thanks for you help and time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: By inner joining with `cte` you eliminate the rows with null arrival dates, so adding `or arrival is null` to the main `WHERE` won't help. And why do you need the CTE in the first place? *UPDATE:* I've seen the original answer and now see that the CTE and the main select had filters by different columns at first. But now that the filters are same you don't seem to need the CTE, do you?

Comment: @Andriy I think it is not totally clear what to OP wants but as I see it he needs two passes of the data. First to figure out what `fid`(s) fit in the date interval (the cte), and then use that to get all rows where `fid` is equal and `arrival` are in the interval or `arrival is null`. I think the cte (or a nested select) is necessary to include the row where `fid=10 and arrival is null` and exclude the row where `fid=20 and arrival is null`. Prove me wrong and you get my vote :)

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Ah yes, the CTE is still meaningful, it's only used to select the `fid`s concerned. I don't know why I couldn't see that first. Well, I'm sorry for not proving you wrong as you asked. :) And *you* get *my* vote.

Answer (score 1):

I think should work:

```
select * from @tbl 
where (arrival >= '2011-02-25' and arrival < '2011-02-28')
and (created >= '2011-02-20' or created is Null)
```

As per your Edit you will need to do this:

```
select * from @tbl 
where ((arrival >= '2011-02-25' and arrival < '2011-02-28') or arrival is null)
and (created >= '2011-02-20' or created is Null)
```

This will return the 3rd FID = 10 row, however it will also return the row ID = 2 and FID = 20 because that row also satisfies the filter conditions.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. That is the problem. I have tried this in my real data. I have 1000's of rows having NULL in this field in real data and this returns all. Any other solution of this or I have to use temp tables or CTEs to get needed result set.

Comment: @Muhammad - Well you can't really filter rows out if the data isn't there to filter on. The row satisfies your conditions so it is going to be returned. I don't really know what else to say?

Comment: hmmmm, you are quite right but condition is I need to include rows like this in result set. I don't want to re-run the whole query to include data, but I think this is the only way. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different take from the more obvious answers posted above

`select * from @tbl 
where arrival >= '2011-02-25' and arrival < '2011-02-28'
and COALESCE(created,'2011-02-25') >= '2011-02-20'`